# C# WinSCP give user option to accept or reject RSA Key

Tags: c#, public-key, winscp

I'm using WinSCP to transfer some files over to another system, but I'm running into some of problems.  Since I was going to use this C# program on various devices the Keys are not the same, so I would like to print out a message box or something similar to the user giving them the option that you would normally see through WinSCP.com:

```
winscp> (U)pdate,(A)dd,Can(n)cel,(C)opy Key,(S)kip: Cancel
```

Right now I'm displaying the options to the user with `winscp.StandardOutput.ReadLine()` and giving them a choice what the return with `winscp.StandardInput.WriteLine([user choice])` but this dosn't seem to work.  I keep getting "Host Key Wasn't Verified!".  Any suggestions on how to approach this one?  Thanks.

Edit:
I believe this has something to do with WinSCP not waiting for input.  I changed the echo option to 'on' so I could see my response and my response occures after WinSCP has already rejected the connection.

My options on WinSCP are currently: batch abort, confirm on, echo on.

So now I guess is there anyway for WinSCP to wait for my commands from the .exe?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So far I've got it working via a "psudo" first connection.  I know it's not very pretty and people will (and probably should) scream at me for doing it this way.  First off I make an attempted connection to the end device,

```
winscp.StandardInput.WriteLine(open scp://name:pass@xx.xx.xx.xx);
```

But that's just to get the key from the end device since I can scan the outputs from winscp and find a message that happens to show that lovely key.  So then, now knowing my device's RSA key I can then prompt the user: 'You're CPU dosn't know this device... Connect anyways?' [yes/no/cancel].  If they say yes then I can explicitly give winscp the hostkey I'm looking for and connect,

```
winscp.StandardInput.WriteLine(open scp://name:pass@xx.xx.xx.xx -hostkey: *****);
```

Like I said it's not the prettiest, and I'd like to do it with a single connection attempt.  But whatever gets the job done right?  I'm still looking into this for a better option.